# How to retrieve a user photo by referring userid from firestore?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know to how to retrieve user photo by its userID. I can fetch current user photo easily. But there is information about how to fetch other in google documents.

To fetch current user photo:

```
let data = NSData(contentsOf: (user?.photoURL)!)
    let userImage = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
    userPhoto?.texture = SKTexture(image: userImage!)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access another user's details in that manner in `Firebase Auth`.  The way to do this in `Firestore` would be to:

1. Create a `Collection`, for example called `UserPhotos`
2. When a user signs in, you can store their `photoURL` in a new document in `UserPhotos` using their `uid` as the `DocumentReference`
3. You can then `.getDocument` on whatever `uid` you want the `photoURL` for.

You would need to make it clear in your privacy policy that you are doing this, and also make sure that the photoURL's are kept upto date.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have all the users in `users` database and you have a photo url for each user. You can get photos of all users by:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
// You will get users photo url in print
print(snapshot.value)
}
```

You can retrieve current user's info by this way:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
if let user = user {
  let uid = user.uid
  let email = user.email
  let photoURL = user.photoURL
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I am trying to get another user photo. I can get current user. But I don't know how to get another user's.

Comment: @TomB. Updated the answer. Check it out again.